# How to move a UILabel's center in a NSMutableArray of UILabels, depends on where user touches and drags that UILabel to?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have a NSMutableArray of UILabels.
I need to be able to select a particular UILabel in this NSMutableArray upon a user touch, and move the center of this touch UILabel to where the user drags their finger to.

I am able to move a particular UILabel in my bunchOfLabels NSMutableArray by doing:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer;
touchPosition = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mainView];
NSLog(@"x: %f", touchPosition.x);

UILabel *temp;
temp = [bunchOfLabels objectAtIndex:0];
temp.center = touchPosition;
```

this will always move the first label, even if the user touches 2nd, 3rd, or whatever label.

but I need to be able to say, move objectAtIndex:4 UILabel anywhere the user touches and drags on a objectAtIndex:4 UILabel to.

I'm a beginner, could somebody please help me out with this? Thanks!

Added info:
I'm currently using UIPanGestureRecognizer, like this:

```
-(void)setupLabels {

    bunchOfLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[characters count]];

    for (int i=0; i < [characters count]; i++)  {

        int xPosition = arc4random() % 518;
        int yPosition = arc4random() % 934;

        UILabel *tempCharacterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, 60, 60)];
        tempCharacterLabel.text = [characters objectAtIndex:i]; // characters is another NSMutableArray contains of NSStrings
        [tempCharacterLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [bunchOfLabels addObject:tempCharacterLabel];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panElement:)];
        [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
        [[bunchOfLabels objectAtIndex:i] addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    }
}

-(void)panElement:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    UILabel *temp;
    temp = [bunchOfLabels objectAtIndex:1];
    temp.center = touchPosition;
}
```

Everything is OK so far, but I've stuck at being able to move a particular UILabel in bunchOfLabels (in the code above, objectAtIndex:1).

Answer (score 3):

Hurray!!! Got it!
I make panElement as below and it works now!

```
-(void)panElement:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:tempLabel];

    tempLabel.center = CGPointMake(tempLabel.center.x + translation.x, tempLabel.center.y + translation.y);

    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:tempLabel];
}
```

Thanks to those attempting to answer my question!